# Down-voted immediately after posting a question on SO. Can it be system initiated or by a user?

Tags: discussion

I am surprised to see an intimidate down vote to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164654/handling-a-running-asynctask-on-orientation-change) on SO, the moment I posted it. Its like some one was waiting to down vote it promptly. AFAIK, user votes here and there is no filters/templates to check certain keywords on the post and generate vote by the system based on those keywords/template.

At least a question like the one I asked, need one or two minutes to be read and understood. I have done good amount of research and tried many ways to solve it. Still not being clear and having some doubt made me to post it here.

Some of my earlier questions was down voted ruthlessly. Some with reason I can consider to be logical, but some with out any logic.(at least I feel so.But different people interpret rule differently!)

Is there any way to know if you are being targeted for down vote?
How to save yourselves from it?
(I am getting started with SO and I don't feel like posting anything here :( )

Comment: Somebody fat-fingered trying to hit the favorite link so he could get back to your question later and hit the DV button instead.  An Android liability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I know of that you'd get a downvote from the system is if someone flagged your post as spam or offensive. In these cases, the Community user will downvote. Even then, I do not think there is a way by which such a flag would be raised without a *user* raising the flag.

It is more likely that someone actually clicked the downvote button. We cannot read their mind. Maybe they were careless. Maybe they meant to upvote you but their cat bumped their elbow and they clicked the wrong button and did not catch the error. (True story: it happened that I misvoted due to one of my cats bumping my elbow but I caught the error right away.) Maybe they misread your question.

As for how long it takes to decide that a question is not useful, it can often be done very quickly. It is possible someone decided your post was not useful based on a problem they saw with your question.

> Is there any way to know if you are being targeted for down vote?

The only form of targeting that is recognized is serial voting: someone going through your profile and voting up or down your posts. If you see a bunch of votes in a short time span in your profile, that's a sign of serial voting. There is a script that detects such occurrences and reverses such votes. If someone just happened to downvote you randomly and it is a single occurrence, there's no recourse really.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Cat bumping their elbow may be the right in some cases, seriously. As I have seen few up votes also afterwards :)

Answer (score 6):

A misclick on the vote button is a real possibility, as mentioned. However, if I had stumbled upon such a question in the tags I follow, I might have downvoted it quickly as well.

At first glance this looks like a far too long code dump for this problem, far from being  a [sscce](http://sscce.org).
You obviously already did some work to remove code superfluous to the problem, but on one hand there still seems to be a lot of lines that have nothing to do with the problem, on the other hand I get the impression that a reader trying to reproduce your problem would need to add quite a bit to get it to even compile.

As I am not familiar with the android-java topic I am not sure of my judgment of this question. Perhaps narrowing the code further down is not really practical in this case, and perhaps an expert would immediately see that the only things missing to test this code snippet is some standard boilerplate stuff.

However in that case I would recommend adding some justificating remarks for the code, so these properties are more apparent. At the very least make it easier to find the line at which the exception occurs.

As it is, my thought process upon seeing such a question would probably go like this:

- hmm, looks interesting
- bah, huge code block, tons of work, answer unlikely to be helpful for anyone but the OP.
- downvote & back button